# Make dynamic Page transition effect in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to change page transition effect from code behind my code is following

```
<transc:TransitionElement x:Name="TransitionBox">
    <transc:TransitionElement.Transition>
        <transt:RotateTransition Angle="45" />
    </transc:TransitionElement.Transition>
</transc:TransitionElement>
```

I want to change or set  from code behind

Please Help me

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you are using that you may be able to do:

```
this.TransitionBox.Transition = new RotateTransition() { Angle = 45 };
```

If you have it in a ControlTemplate or a DataTemplate, then things get a bit more complicated.